# Pivot_longer dependent on value in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

My df looks like this:

```
Name   V1         V2         V3         choice
Apple  sports     sports     sports     v2
Banana hobbies    hobbies    hobbies    v3
Mango  interests  interests  interests  v1
```

I would like to manipulate the df to look like this using pivot_longer:

```
Name   choice choice_word
Apple  v2     hobbies
Banana v3     interests
Mango  v1     sports
```

Unfortunately, I could not find an appropriate answer online. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without `pivot_longer` - grouped by row (`rowwise`), convert the 'choice' to upper case (`R` is case sensitive), extract the column value with `[[` from the data (`cur_data()`), `ungroup` and remove the columns not needed

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(choice_word = cur_data()[[toupper(choice)]]) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-(V1:V3))
```

---

If the 'v1', to 'v3', in 'choice' are the row numbers, then do

```
df1 %>% 
  transmute(Name, choice, 
     choice_word =  .[cbind(readr::parse_number(choice), 2:4)])
```

-output

```
    Name choice choice_word
1  Apple     v2     hobbies
2 Banana     v3   interests
3  Mango     v1      sports
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Apple", "Banana", "Mango"), V1 = c("sports", 
"hobbies", "interests"), V2 = c("sports", "hobbies", "interests"
), V3 = c("sports", "hobbies", "interests"), choice = c("v2", 
"v3", "v1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```